# knowing the caller object or thread from static method

Tags: java, multithreading, object, static

I have a static method of a class and which is being called from another non static method from an object or thread.
Is there a way to know that from which thread or object it was called?
I think it's not possible and I need it for nothing, but just want to confirm it.

I mean something like this

```
class CallerID
{
    public static void main(String ...s)
    {
        CallerID ob=new CallerID();
        ob.caller();
    }
    void caller()
    {
        showCaller();
        System.out.println("In this method, ob = "+this);
    }
    static void showCaller()
    {
        //code to get caller object ob like it is printed in method caller()
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do you want the calling object, or the current thread? Those are completely different things. `Thread.currentThread()` returns the current thread.

Comment: *"Is there a way to know that from which thread or object it was called?"* Your question makes no sense.

Comment: It's not possible, but your actual problem can probably be solved in a better way. Tell us what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @Nizet as I said "I need it for nothing". Just trying something. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I could imagine a complex setup that used AOP to create some kind of context database that allowed you to lookup the calling object if you wanted - but I can't think of why you would want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the object calling. You can get the calling object, thread, and method, but if you want a reference you'll have to pass `this` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can print a stack trace to know from which thread and object it is called.

Comment: not the object, just the method and class, and you don't need to print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
StackTraceElement[] el = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

to look at the backtrace and from this you can find the caller there.

Answer (score 1):

The thread could be found with `Thread.currentThread()`.
The calling object although cannot be found. The calling method could be found by parsing a stack trace, although that might be quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in thread's most recent stack trace, usually its the fourth entry, or you can iterate to check:

```
 StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
 if(trace.length > 3){
   System.out.println("Called from method " + trace[3].getMethodName() + " of class " + trace[3].getClassName());
 }
```